# When does the ServletContext return a null RequestDispatcher?

Tags: java, servlets

The api for [ServletContext#getRequestDispatcher()](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)) says:

> This method returns null if the ServletContext cannot return a RequestDispatcher.

and

> Returns:
>   a RequestDispatcher object that acts as a wrapper for the resource at the specified path, or null if the ServletContext cannot return a RequestDispatcher

For what reason would the ServletContext not be able to return a RequestDispatcher?  At first I figured it would be if an invalid path was passed but that doesn't return null, it results in a 404 on the browser.

I am checking for null before calling the forward() method and in the logs I can see that once in awhile the RequestDispatcher is null but I don't know why and I can't find out how to duplicate it.

Thanks

**Update**

Like Fazal suggested I tried created a RequestDispatcher to 'http://www.google.com/' to see what would happen.  This caused an IllegalArgumentException

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path http://www.google.com/ does not start with a "/" character

The Exception was caught in my try/catch block so I never got the chance to check if the RequestDispatcher was null or call the forward() method.

So there must be another way for the ServletContext#getRequestDispatcher() method to return null without throwing an Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat returns `null` for path outside of the current context, such as `/../foo` (but Jetty doesn't, so it's implementation-specific).

Comment: Ahh, I see I was missing the '../'.  I am running on Tomcat and you're right it did return null.  Also I noticed that if the path passed to getRequestDispatcher() is null then it will return null too.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue intermittently. But for me this only happens, if you are trying to go to a valid patch which is not in the document root. 
E.g. Your Server is running at http://localhost/
and I do a forward to a URL like http://www.google.com. Not sure if you run into this issue

Comment: Hmm, I decided to try creating a RequestDispatcher to http://www.google.com/ and it threw an IllegalArgumentException because the Path does not start with a "/" character.