# getRequestDispatcher() is returning null (Portlet)

Tags: java, jboss, liferay, portlet

I am working on a Java Portlet (extending GenericPortlet), using JBoss 7.02 and LifeRay Portal 6.1.0 GA1. This is one of the bundles that can be downloaded from LifeRay's release archive.

During deployment, when the init() method is called, getRequestDispatcher() returns null. Below is the exact error message:

> 09:22:15,972 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/my-portlet-name]] (MSC service thread 1-15) Error during mapping: java.lang.NullPointerException

Below is a snippet from my init() method:

```
PortletConfig config = getPortletConfig();
PortletContext context = getPortletContext();
PortletRequestDispatcher normalView = context.getRequestDispatcher("/portlet.jsp");
```

As a temporary workaround, I have moved all `getRequestDispatcher()` calls to `doView()` where it executes without problem. I do not understand why `getRequestDispatcher()` can locate portlet.jsp when called during doView, but not when its called during `init()`

Am I missing a preceding call of some other method that would resolve this? Is this a known issue?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the request dispatcher in the `doView` is the only place I've seen it done. I would imagine that it returns null during `init` because there is no actual request to dispatch.

Typically the `init` method is used for time-expensive operations that you don't want to incur for each request. This might be something like reading data from a file, or creating a reusable SQL connection.

You should also keep in mind that you should keep any portlet state thread safe. Don't create class or object variables that can only be used for one request at a time. The portlet methods are not inhererently thread safe, so you need to make sure that whatever variables a request is interacting with won't be manipulated by another request that is executing concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If `doView` is the appropriate place to make those calls then that works for me. `init` just seemed like a good place to put them.
Thanks for the thread-safe warning; I had not considered that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Portlets, but the answer should be the same as for Servlets.

The `init()` method is called exactly once, when your application is initially deployed.  There is no active request (no one is asking for anything) or response (no one is going to read what the output is). Therefore, it is very reasonable for`getRequestDispatcher(`) to return null.  In `doView()`, when you're handling a request and response, it makes sense to ask another resource to generate part (or all) of the response.

To address your question directly, `getRequestDispatcher(`) has no problem locating `portlet.jsp` from `init()`; it's the request that's missing.  (Where do you expect to see the result of `portlet.jsp`, anyway?)

If you do want to print some output during initialization, you can try logging it to a file, if your application is set up for that.  Or, you can display data on `System.out`, if you know where the container's console is.  (I use this second option quite often with servlets.)

Comment: Just noticed this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815028/when-does-the-servletcontext-return-a-null-requestdispatcher
I think the scenario in this question answers the other question.